# Amazon EC2 - Change SQL Server from Standard to Web

Tags: sql-server, amazon-ec2, licensing

We have a web application running on an EC2 instance that was built using the SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard AMI.

We have since noticed that the cost of Standard is substantially higher than the cost for Web.

I cannot find any reason to indicate why it would not be acceptable to run under the Web licence of SQL Server.

Is there any way to modify / update the licencing on the stance to go to Web from Std?

I am hoping there is a simple setting / key thing that can be done, rather than having to create a new instance with the Web licence and re-installing.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you are taking advantage of advanced SQL Server Standard edition features such as failover and mirroring, then you definitely should consider moving over to the Web edition. Amazon (currently) charges an additional $0.514/hr for the SQL Server Standard license, but only an additional $0.04/hr for the SQL Server Web license. If your server is running 24/7 for a year, you will save over $4000. Even if you really need SQL Server Standard, I would imagine you'd be better off just buying your own license and installing it on a regular Windows AMI, avoiding the extra per hour cost altogether. As for the hassle of having to migrate to a new instance, it shouldn't be too bad. Just backup the DB, copy the code and IIS settings, and then modify your DNS to the new IP. (Or ask AMZ to move the IP for you to the new server.) Note that a SQL Server backup from Standard will restore cleanly to Web, but only if the Web is the same version or higher than the Standard.

Comment: Yes, I know that the standard edition is much more expensive, hence my question. Unfortunately, the migration to a new instance is not hassle free. It is not simply an IIS container running a site. It runs a third party web application that runs on TomCat and has extremely strict licencing that means that only they are able to install / uninstall it. Hence I was looking for a simple setting / key.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so that flexibility you will get in AMAZON EC2 , you have to migrate your instance .